# Javascript Age Document.write, help print out both statements 18 and over and 50 and over?

Tags: javascript

I need help printing out messages based on an input age.  If I put in the age 55, it'll print "You're okay to drive!" and "Must have medical checkup."  If I put in the age 20, it will only print the first message.

This is the code I've written so far:

```
<script>
function Driving() {
var Drive;
age = prompt("Please, put in your age");


if (age >= 18){
    document.write("You're okay to drive!");
}

else if (age == 50){
document.write("Must have medical checkup.");

} else {
    document.write("Too young to drive.");
    }
return;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="Driving()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lcz281c/1/

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/3Lcz281c/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to nest the if statement.

```
if (age >= 18) {
  document.write("Your okay to drive!<br>");
  if (age >= 50) {
    document.write("Must have medical checkup.");
  }
} else {
  document.write("Too young to drive.");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cowdd/1hsjy8j3/

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to accept an answer, thanks